# Call Object with string - Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Text file working as data base in the following format

```
btnBar/Cafe/3.5
btnBar_0/Bebida/1.0
btnBar_1/Sumo/2.0
  ^       ^    ^
  |       |    |
btn var |text|price
```

GUI:
[image]

```
    InputStream is = MainWindow.class.getResourceAsStream("DB.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(is)
```

Using this while scanner has a next line its has to set every gui button name,price....What methodology should I use?

Comment: Not an answer. It should be `desiredString.equals("btn1")`

Comment: Sounds a lot like an X-Y problem.  Why do you need to do this?  Where does `desiredString` actually come from?  Do you instead need your buttons to be in a collection of some kind where they can be referenced by a key?  Such as in an array or a map?

Comment: @NengLiu off-topic: effective java says "btn1".equals(desiredString)...

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski That's better.

Comment: @David makes a good point. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Yep, there's bound to be a better solution if we know more about the overall problem, rather than how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the article @AndrewThompson.

Comment: So what I meant is
How do I access a Button with the same variable name as my chosen string value? Probably more correct right?

Comment: No, better to show more of the program so we can see what you're trying to do. You're putting way too much importance on variable names when you should be focusing on *references*. Variable names almost don't exist in compiled code.

Comment: *"Probably more correct right?"* No, not really. What @David, HovercraftFullOfEels and I are trying to get at is that although it is ***possible*** to look up buttons by a `String` reference, there are *very, **very*** few cases in which that is actually the **best approach.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok so I have a text file working as a "Database" which is in the format of (btnVariable/Text of Button/Number) and a GUI with lots of buttons, which I'm trying to access so i can set the text and later on use those values to sum and print for example. So the point is getting the values from db.txt and set them to the right buttons.

Comment: @AndréMoreira: please consider [edit]ing your question (click on the link) and giving us more detail and more relevant code. Showing some of the text file (formatted as code) and even images of the GUI might help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case would like to create a `Map<String, JButton>` like so :

```
Map<String, JButton> buttons = new HashMap<>();
buttons.put("btn1", button1);
buttons.put("btn2", button2);
buttons.put("btn3", button3);
```

Then if you want to get the button with the name you can just use :

```
String desiredString = "btn2";
buttons.get(desiredString). //Your action here
```

Comment: Not working: " at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)"

Comment: @AndréMoreira You changed all the context of your question, the first version doesn't said that at all, beside can you show us your try please that gives you that error?

Comment: Oh it's working after all, thanks. I had goofed up in a match!

Comment: Clever and effective solution